# how to cleanup after Rake::PackageTask and how to redirect its output?

Tags: ruby, rake, rake-task

Ahead of creating a tarball we are generating several files to be added to the package. For example:

```
# from Rakefile

# generate fileA (copy is just an example, the file is really generated dynamically)
FileUtils.cp("fileA", "myFileA")

Rake::PackageTask.new("package name") do |p|
    p.need_tar_gz = true
    p.package_files.include("myFileA") # generated a few lines before
end
```

After executing `rake package` it is just the right time for cleanup (to remove `myFileA` that was copied on purpose). The question is how to do it right?